# Date Format MMM is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datepicker

The jquery function for popuping the calender :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#basic_example_4').datetimepicker({         
     });
     $( "#basic_example_4" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd MMM  yy" );
});
```

This is my input tag

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  id="basic_example_4" name="expiration"     placeholder="Expiration Date" readonly="readonly"/>
```

When am selecting the date from date picker i want to display like `03 Aug 2014` , Changes in above format is reflecting to the code but in additon to that am facing the problem i.e date is printing as `03 AugustAug 2014`, For why its printing full name of month before 3 chars of the month name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be only one "M" and not three.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#basic_example_4').datepicker();
 $( "#basic_example_4" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd M yy" );
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhahcm97/2/)